# Oxirane and ring opening

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

I have a problem given as :- [image] I thought of a sn1 type mechanism in acidic medium and a sn2 pathway in basic medium .  Am I correct or not . Please also check the mechanism according to which I formed the answer for acidic conditions......[image] help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Looks about right

Comment: Any improvements that could be made ?

Comment: Note that the selectivity in the SN2 addition is driven by steric factors